# Symfony2 - "Invalid Resource Exception" when translating twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to translate labels in my twig template located in Resources/views/User/ folder:

```
<label for="username">{% trans %}Username{% endtrans %} </label>
```

And the following is a section from my login.ka.xliff file located in my project under "translations" folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Username</source>
                <target>მომხმარებელი</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

and this is my route to the login page:

```
login:
    path:     /login/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ExampleBundle:LogIn:login }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|ka
```

I have two problems:

1. When I try to open the login page with a locale (say, ka) I get the:

   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
    1 linked Exception:
    InvalidResourceException »
2. I know I can get the locale from request using $request->getLocale(); but how do I specify that login page should use login.ka.xliff file for translations?

   Ok, I seem to have provided not enough info, so here it is:

   I put my translation file in Example:MyBundle:Resources:translations (this is what I meant above "in my project").

   I get exception when rending my login view and the following is the full version of the exception I get:

   "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("")  in   ExampleMyBundle:User:login.html.twig at line 32.

   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
   1 linked Exception:
   InvalidResourceException »"

   And yes, I did try clearing cache each time I made changes, but it didn't help.

   And also, I added the complete version of my login.ka.xliff file.

   Thanks again!

Comment: Which `translations` folder did you use to store the translation file ? ... in your project-root , app/Resources ? Please add that information to the question - it's important information needed to diagnose the problem! ... and **clear your cache** btw. :) Further add the relevant parts of the exception message - we need to see **where** the exception has been thrown. The name of the exception alone doesn't enable us to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I added more information to my question. Hope that makes the error more clear now

Comment: Did you add a default domain named "login" ? if not - the filename is wrong but that might not be the only issue. Please study the cookbook article about translation domains in my answer. Is line 32 actually this `{% trans %}Username{% endtrans %}` line - please confirm that. Did you clear your cache ? What happens if you use `{{ 'Username'|trans }}` instead?

Comment: So, I tried specifying default domain "{% trans_default_domain "login" %}" in my template and although it renders with no exception, it doesn't translate the label. I clear cache everytime and I read the Translations documentation very carefully :( And yes, that's the line number where error occurs (32)

Answer (score 0):

Your xliff file seems to be invalid - it should look like this: ( containing the xml-namespace, body, ... ).

```
<!-- messages.ka.xliff -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Username</source>
                <target>მომხმარებელი</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

The file should be named `messages.ka.xliff` if you haven't actually specified a different [translation domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#using-message-domains) in your template!

```
{{ 'Username'|trans({}, "login") }}
```

... or configured a different default translation-domain in your template ...

```
{% trans_default_domain "login" %}
```

---

```
<trans-unit id="1">
   <source>Username</source>
   <target>მომხმარებელი</target>
</trans-unit>
```

... is an invalid xliff-file.

Comment: I used the default {% trans_default_domain "login" %} in my template but it won't translate the content.